# Laravel: Use of Auth sometimes returns error: call to member function parameter() on array

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, request, lumen

I have an API that uses the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth` class to make HTTP requests to several different services within each service's respective repository. This is the structure I use for one such request, with `httpClient` referencing an implementation of `GuzzleHttp`:

```
$items = $this->httpClient->get(
    env('INVENTORY_URI').'item?'.http_build_query($query),
    Auth::user()->get('token')
);
```

All of the API's requests are structured in this manner and have been tested to work. However on certain repositories, referencing the Auth class returns this error:

> Call to a member function parameter() on array

I have no clue as to why only some of these calls to Auth throw this error, as the requests are virtually identical to each other.

**Update:** I managed to trace the exception farther down to the `AuthServiceProvider`, but the exception's true cause still eludes me. My `boot()` function is coded as follows:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app['auth']->viaRequest('api', function ($request) {
        if ($request->auth) // Exception thrown at this point
        {
            return new Collection(json_decode($request->auth, true));
        }
    });
}
```

On a more specific note, and to restate the previously mentioned fact, this exception only occurs on 4 out of 44 requests.

**Update 2:** I used `dd()` to dump the request object from the `AuthServiceProvider` and [took a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tgftl.jpg) of the results. To the left is the Request object when dumped during a functional HTTP request and to the right is the Request object when dumped during an HTTP request that would throw the error.

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with Routing in lumen: https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/685. Also looks like a fix might be in place: https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/pull/803

Comment: Thanks! I was also thinking about making my own Request class to extend the original one and work around the function call. It did work!